# Laravel + voyager - php artisan config:cache = error ('avatar' of non-object)

Tags: php, laravel, voyager

Here are the logs

> [2020-09-27 14:12:31] local.ERROR: Trying to get property 'avatar' of
> non-object (View:
> /home/servername/domains/mydomain/subdomain/vendor/tcg/voyager/resources/views/master.blade.php)
> {"exception":"[object] (Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException(code:
> 0): Trying to get property 'avatar' of non-object (View:
> /home/servername/domains/mydomain/subdomain/vendor/tcg/voyager/resources/views/master.blade.php)
> at
> /home/servername/domains/mydomain/subdomain/vendor/tcg/voyager/src/../resources/views/master.blade.php:67)

Here is the code: 67 start from the `if`

```
 <?php
if (\Illuminate\Support\Str::startsWith(Auth::user()->avatar, 'http://') || \Illuminate\Support\Str::startsWith(Auth::user()->avatar, 'https://')) {
    $user_avatar = Auth::user()->avatar;
} else {
    $user_avatar = Voyager::image(Auth::user()->avatar);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting

```
use TCG\Voyager\Http\Middleware\VoyagerAdminMiddleware;
```

and

```
$this->middleware(VoyagerAdminMiddleware::class);
```

in the construct.

Comment: Can you explain the construct? I did not understand, where to put these lines that you mentioned.